# .NET Core 3.1 web application with React - how to prevent access based on Active Directory group

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 web application with React using windows authentication.
When a user enters their Active Directory credentials i would like to verify they belong to a particular Active Directory group before allowing access to the React app.

I have tried setting the default endpoint to a Login Controller to verify the user's groups but i don't know how to redirect to the React app if they do have the valid group.

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {                
      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
          name: "default",
          pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
          defaults: new { Controller = "Login", action = "Index" });
  });
```

LoginController:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string[] domainAndUserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
             //AuthenticateUser verifies if the user is in the correct Active Directory group
            if (AuthenticateUser(domainAndUserName[0], domainAndUserName[1]))
            {
                //This is where i would like to redirect to the React app
                return Ok(); //This does not go to the react app
                return LocalRedirect("http://localhost:50296/"); //This will keep coming back to this method
            }
            return BadRequest();            
        }
}
```

Is it possible to redirect to the React app from the controller?
Is there a better way to verify an active directory group, possibly through authorizationService.js?

Comment: you can handle it in Authorization filter.

Comment: Can you provide any details or a link to something that could get me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Here is one link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Instead of _return LocalRedirect(string)_, use _return Page()_ or _return RedirectToPage("/Index")_ or whatever your default page is.

Comment: Nope. I was wrong above. I think this line should do it for you :)

`return RedirectPermanent("http://localhost:50296/");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in this situation before, and solved it with custom implementation of IClaimsTransformation. This approach may also be used with OpenId Connect and other authentication systems that requires additional authorization.

With this approach, you can use authorize attribute on controller that serves your React app

```
[Authorize(Roles = "HasAccessToThisApp")]
```

and

```
User.IsInRole("HasAccessToThisApp")
```

elsewhere in code.

Implementation. Please note that TransformAsync will be called on every request, some caching is recommended if any time-consuming calls.

```
public class YourClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public YourClaimsTransformer(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(incomingPrincipal);
        }

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name)
             && _cache.TryGetValue(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name, out ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity))
        {
            principal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
            return Task.FromResult(principal);
        }

        // verifies that the user is in the correct Active Directory group
        var domainAndUserName = incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name?.Split('\\');
        if (!(domainAndUserName?.Length > 1 && AuthenticateUser(domainAndUserName[0], domainAndUserName[1])))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(incomingPrincipal);
        }

        var newClaimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "HasAccessToThisApp", ClaimValueTypes.String)

                // copy other claims from incoming if required

            }, "Windows");

        _cache.Set(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name, newClaimsIdentity,
            DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));

        principal.AddIdentity(newClaimsIdentity);
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

In Startup#ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, YourClaimsTransformer>();
```

Comment: Updated my answer with something more simple. You actually don't need IUserRepo to solve this.

Comment: This works great!  Thank you.  Can you share how you cached this to lessen the calls?

Comment: Made a small improvement in order to reduce number of calls to AuthenticateUser.

Comment: I can't get my head around why we need to cache things that we're adding to the user's claims. Surely the whole point of adding claims, which are then stored in the authentication cookie, is that they're cached in the cookie. If I have to read the values from the memory cache each time anyway, what's the point in adding them as claims? I might as well just get the values from the memory cache rather than ther user's claims wherever I need them in the app.