# .Net Core 3.1 ClaimsTransformation Manually Added Claims Not Persisting

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, claims-authentication

I will be accessing several tables to determine if a user is "Validated" or not as well as adding custom roles to a Windows authenticated user for authorization.  For now I'm running a test in a basic .net Core web application just to see how I should be doing this.  I have setup a RequiredClaim in my Fallback Policy and a ClaimsLoader and it works great:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsLoader>();
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireClaim("ValidatedUser")
                .Build();
        });
    }


    public class ClaimsLoader : IClaimsTransformation
    {
       public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
       {
          var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
          claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("ValidatedUser", ""));
          return await Task.FromResult(principal);
       }
    }
```

As long as that AddClaim line is in there, they can access the app, without it they get a not-authorized response which is what I want.

Based on what I've read I thought any claims/roles I add in the transformation should come back each time but they do not.  In the code above I have the AddClaim running every time so it's working, but in reality I will be going to a database to determine if I should add that claim which is an expensive process.  I want to persist the results across multiple requests.  So I want to check if the claim is already there and not bother getting it again if it is.  For whatever reason it is NEVER there when it comes back for a second request.

From what I've read here back in 2.x the claims should persist:
https://philipm.at/2018/aspnetcore_claims_with_windowsauthentication.html

But here in my 3.1 application they do not.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to accept that TransformAsync is called on every request. The good news is that caching will reduce number of calls to db. Complete solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63441045/14072498

Comment: That is the exact code I was already working with.  :)  I expect TransformAsync  to be called on every request I was just confused how my article seemed to think that the roles and claims added at TransformAsync  would be persisted:   "..which means for IIS Authentication they run only once and whatever claims we add to the collection are cached for as long as the user is logged in."   

So I had expected to put code in TransformAsync  to make sure I don't add them in TWICE but it doesn't matter - anything I add is only there for that single request.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the exact same place as you were, @KevinFizz. My claims are only persisted if they're added during the authentication process. Even though `TransformAsync` is called repeatedly by the app, any changes made there to claims aren't persisted from one call to the next. I've read the answer referenced by @Roar S., but the solution of adding the values to the memory cache seems to completely defeat the purpose of claims, which is to "cache" attributes relating to the user in the authentication cookie. If I have to add the claims over and over again, what's the point of them?